# Jquery - code being used

Tags: jquery

I have this code in a script.
I know what the result is, but not what it's actually doing.

```
var str = ',' + id + ',' + name;

names = names.map(function(value) {
if( value.indexOf(id) > -1 ) {
    return (value.indexOf('add') === 0 ? 'add' : 'edit') + str;
}
return value;
});

if ( ($.inArray('edit' + str, names) == -1  && $.inArray('add' + str, names) == -1)   ) {
    names.push('edit' + str)
}
```

The person who gave me the script isn't available for comments.

it seems to be is `str` isn't in the array add it, if it is update it.

Can anyone give a brief overview of what it actually does.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's looking for specifically `'edit'+str` and `'add'+str` in the `names` array. If both are not present, then add `'edit'+str` to the `names` array.

```
var str = ',' + id + ',' + name;

names = names.map(function(value) {
if( value.indexOf(id) > -1 ) { //if id is in value
    return (value.indexOf('add') === 0 ? 'add' : 'edit') + str; //if value starts with 'add' then return 'add'+str, otherwise return 'edit'+str
}
return value; //if id not in value, return value
});

if ( ($.inArray('edit' + str, names) == -1  && $.inArray('add' + str, names) == -1)   ) { //If 'edit'+str is not in the names array AND 'add'+str is not in the names array
    names.push('edit' + str) //add 'edit'+str to the names array
}
```

Comment: Great thanks.  I want to try and work out how to turn this into a function. So I can pass `str` and `names` to the function allowing the same code to be used for testing the same criteria in different arrays.